# How do I remove weird characters in text?

Tags: characters

Help, my site is suddenly populated with weird characters, like this:

> â€œDo what you love and do it often,â€ â€œIf you donâ€™t like your job, quit,â€ and â€œTravel often; Getting lost will help you find yourself.â€

What do I do to remove it?

[Link to Website](http://causecapitalism.com).

[image: Here's an example.]

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Comment: "Suddenly"? You really should find out, what has corrupted your data – this looks like the charset of either your database, database connection or HTML document has changed. Best option to get rid of those garbled chars, is to restore a backup of your database. In case you didn't have a backup start crying now and swear, that you will store backups regularly from now on.

Comment: Your content is sent with a wrong charset value. An image won't do it, add a real URL to your question so we can see the HTTP headers.

Comment: The site is causecapitalism.com

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the site is still using the Unicode character set from the page header, but the database may have been corrupted. Ask Linode for a backup restore and/or if they changed anything with their MySQL servers.

If you don't run your own regular database backups, you should. Try [WordPress › WP-DB-Backup « WordPress Plugins.](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-db-backup/)

You can also use phpmyadmin at Linode to check the collation of the database and repair it. Or use [WordPress › Portable phpMyAdmin « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/portable-phpmyadmin/) from inside the WP admin.

Answer (score 1):

You can try commenting out the encoding type in the wp-config.  Sometimes that works.

> //define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
>
> //define('DB_COLLATE','utf8_unicode_ci');

Answer (score 0):

I found this post which gave me desired results... This can be remove simply by running a short SQL query on your WordPress database, using the command line client or PhpMyAdmin.

Here's a solution copy/pasted from this [link](http://www.wpbold.com/remove-weird-characters-from-your-wordpress-site/)

**Always keep a backup copy of your database before you make any changes.**

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'â€œ', '“');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'â€', '”');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'â€™', '’');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'â€˜', '‘');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'â€”', '–');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'â€“', '—');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'â€¢', '-');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'â€¦', '…');

UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_content = REPLACE(comment_content, 'â€œ', '“');
UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_content = REPLACE(comment_content, 'â€', '”');
UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_content = REPLACE(comment_content, 'â€™', '’');
UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_content = REPLACE(comment_content, 'â€˜', '‘');
UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_content = REPLACE(comment_content, 'â€”', '–');
UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_content = REPLACE(comment_content, 'â€“', '—');
UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_content = REPLACE(comment_content, 'â€¢', '-');
UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_content = REPLACE(comment_content, 'â€¦', '…');
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, I was still having the problem in front of the "read more" links on summary pages.  Below is what fixed it for me, so I'm posting it here in case anyone else has this exact same scenario.

I'm totally shocked.  After hours of trying things and testing, I finally found the "Settings" then "Readings" option below: "Encoding for pages and feeds".  After changing from UTF-7 to UTF-8, everything looks good again.

[image]

And even stranger, after changing it to UTF-8, the option disappears from the page. According to [WordPress site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_Screen), this option was removed since release 3.5.