# Fix encoding â€™

Tags: encoding

I moved my hosting provider and now the encoding is messed up.  [See here](http://www.helireviews.com/advertising/) for example.  In the past commenting out the follwoing lines fixed the issue for me, but not this time:

> //define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
>
> //define('DB_COLLATE','utf8_unicode_ci');

The hosting provider is saying I need to set it to the correct encoding rather than just comment it out, but I'm unsure what encoding that would be.

Example Text:

> Youâ€™ll be in good company. Join our network of leading RC sponsors
> that have help support the growth of HeliReviews.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove weird characters in text?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50573/how-do-i-remove-weird-characters-in-text)

Comment: That questions says the symbols just appeared, whereas this item is about encoding after moving hosts.

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**. This question appears to be a **SQL data/import** issue, rather than a **WordPress** issue.

Answer (score 3):

The reason commenting out (see q ) didn't work is that the data was wrong in the database, so no encoding change could fix it.

I restored the database by copy pasting the sql script into PHPMyAdmin, and the text box interpreted the text as having the wrong encoding.  By using import in phpmyadmin and selecting the file, that data came in correctly.